# How can I make Javascript/jQuery code display html table in csv file regardless of html format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

You may have to click export button twice to get csv file to appear.

The code in link contains html, css, & Javascript/jQuery. Code to export data to CSV. The code works perfectly, but when I make the table format to be:

```
<tr>
        <td>
            row1 Col1
        </td>
        <td>
            row1 Col2
        </td>
        <td>
            row1 Col3
        </td>
    </tr>
```

The data in table gets cut off when it get's exported to CSV. Is there a way to make Javascript code read html table code in this type of format?

Code

---

CSS:

```
a.export, a.export:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#000;
    background-color:#ddd;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding:8px;
}
```

---

Javascript/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function exportTableToCSV($table, filename) {

        var $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td,th)'),

        // Temporary delimiter characters unlikely to be typed by keyboard
        // This is to avoid accidentally splitting the actual contents
        tmpColDelim = String.fromCharCode(11), // vertical tab character
        tmpRowDelim = String.fromCharCode(0), // null character

        // actual delimiter characters for CSV format
        colDelim = '","',
        rowDelim = '"\r\n"',

        // Grab text from table into CSV formatted string
        csv = '"' + $rows.map(function (i, row) {

            var $row = $(row),
                $cols = $row.find('td, th');

            return $cols.map(function (j, col) {

                var $col = $(col),
                    text = $col.text();
                return text.replace('"', '""'); // escape double quotes
            }).get().join(tmpColDelim);

        }).get().join(tmpRowDelim)
        .split(tmpRowDelim).join(rowDelim)
        .split(tmpColDelim).join(colDelim) + '"',

        // Data URI
        csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);


        $(this).attr({
            'download': filename,
            'href': csvData,
            'target': '_blank'
        });
    }

    // This must be a hyperlink
    $(".export").on('click', function (event) {

        // CSV
        exportTableToCSV.apply(this, [$('#dvData>table'), 'export.csv']);

        // IF CSV, don't do event.preventDefault() or return false
        // We actually need this to be a typical hyperlink
    });
});
```

[Source](http://jsfiddle.net/KPEGU/499/).

Comment: does excel format works for you?

Comment: Your code works really fine. What do you mean by "make the table format to be: row1 Col1 row1 Col2 row1 Col3" ?

Comment: Now I got it ... you just need to remove carriage returns from the cells content. Something like text.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/g,"");

Comment: Go to http://jsfiddle.net/KPEGU/499/ you notice that not all values of the table is being displayed in the csv file. It the html table portion that formatted like:                                     <tr>
<td>
row1 Col1
</td>
<td>
row1 Col2
</td>
<td>
row1 Col3
</td>
</tr>

Comment: You might also need to check for extra white spaces.

Comment: How do I check for extra white spaces in Javascript/jQuery got any references?

Comment: Figured it out I must use the trim function but I'm not telling where.